# Need to print boss names from text file recursively

Tags: java, recursion

In my Java class, we're just now learning about recursion and this is the problem that I'm asked to do. In a text file, there are several lines of employees in this format: Name,Hours,Wage,Boss.

I have a scanner set up and everything works well, except the thing is there is one main boss ("N/A" is what is under his boss field) and then it trees off into different people (in the text file they are not in order.) The task is to print them in order of ranking, ie:

> BossName : Wage
>
> --2nd Employee : Wage
>
> ----3rd Employee : Wage
>
> -- 4th Employee : Wage

This has to be done recursively, and I'm completely stumped. I just can't find out what to put as the "base case" or how to even start it.

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a method which finds all employees with a given boss. Then write another method which, given a boss name and a level, finds the boss and pretty prints him/her, then finds all its employees (by calling the 1st method) and recursively calls itself for each employee.

Call this second method from main with "N/A" as the boss name and 1 as level.

Answer (score 0):

well check this simple source code, maybe it will get you started...

```
import java.io.*;

class test
{
        //main method
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
     {
        String filename = "input.txt";

         // Initialize the reader
         BufferedReader reader = null;
         try {
             reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
         } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

        //recursive call
        myRecursion(reader);

     } //end main

    //method using recursion to read a file
    static void myRecursion(BufferedReader br) 
    {
        String s1 = "";

        try {
             s1 = br.readLine();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

        if(s1 == null)
            return;
        else 
        {
            System.out.println (s1);
            myRecursion(br);
            return;
        }
    } //end method
} //end class
```

The input.txt is:

```
one
two
three
```